# Different labels for different aligned parts of an equation

Tags: labels, alignment, subequations

What is the best way to write something like this

```
\begin{equation}
A=
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& B\\
& C
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}
```

but with two different labels (i.e. equation numbers) for the two right-hand lines after the brace? I am considering several options (like using alignat), not sure what is the best and easiest way to accomplish this result.

Comment: It that is a case-like structure, have a look at the [`cases`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cases) package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `empheq` (which loads `mathtools`, hence `amsmath`):

```
\begin{empheq}[left={A=\empheqlbrace}]{align}
&B \\ &C
\end{empheq}
```